# Trying to plot Negative Values on Plotly Scattered chart

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I am trying to plot negative values on the Plotly Scattered chart.

My Dataset is as following:

```
    word                    mean_score         headline_count
0   Agilent Technologies    0.248711           1
1   Apple                  -0.366803145021645  462
```

My current working code is:

```
def plot_line_chart_for_all(file_name, threshold_score, min_headlines_count):
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    file_path = cwd + "/data/" + file_name

    df = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep="\t")
    df_filtered = df[abs(df['mean_score']) >= threshold_score]
    df_filtered = df_filtered[df_filtered['headline_count'] >= min_headlines_count]

    df_filtered = df_filtered[df_filtered['mean_score'] >= 0.0]
    fig = px.scatter(df_filtered, x='headline_count', y='mean_score', size='mean_score', hover_data=['mean_score', 'headline_count', 'word'],
                     )
    return fig
```

I have searched and learned that Plotly Scatter charts does not support negative values so what I am trying to do is converting negative values to positive values so all of negative and positives shows on the same chart.

I am trying to use ABS() function to convert - values to positive numbers, but with no luck using the code below.

```
def plot_line_chart_for_all(file_name, threshold_score, min_headlines_count):
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    file_path = cwd + "/data/" + file_name

    df = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep="\t")
    df_filtered = df[abs(df['mean_score']) >= threshold_score]
    df_filtered = df_filtered[df_filtered['headline_count'] >= min_headlines_count]

    df_filtered = df_filtered[df_filtered['mean_score'] < 0.0].abs()
    fig = px.scatter(df_filtered, x='headline_count', y='mean_score', size='mean_score', hover_data=['mean_score', 'headline_count', 'word'],
                     )

   

    return fig
```

Appriciate some feedback..

Comment: Why can't scatter plots handle negative data? See examples in the [references](https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/#scatter-with-a-color-dimension).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I wonder why I can not plot all data. I want to plot all data pos and negative.

Comment: How about disabling the size? That may be the cause. The marker size may be assuming a positive number.